# DropDownList - more than 1 item on DataTextField

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to put on `DataTextField` more than 1 item from database (surname and name). How can I do this?
Of course, `DataTextField="surname + name"` doesn't work, but is there any possibility to put together this 2 items?

There is my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dllSpecialist" DataValueField="iduserspecialist" DataTextField="surname" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dllSpecialist_IndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

code behind:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dllSpecialist.DataSource = tUserSpecialistBO.getAllSpecialist();
        dllSpecialist.DataBind();
       (..)
    }
```

sql method:

```
public static DataSet getAllSpecialist()
{

    sql = "select * from tuserspecialist where del='false' and name!=''";
    return SQLTools.getDataSet(sql);
}
```

Comment: why dont you do that in your select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your SQL statement:

```
sql = "select surname + ' ' + name as FullName, iduserspecialist from tuserspecialist where del='false' and name!=''";
```

Then change your property to specify the new data item:

```
DataTextField="FullName"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
SELECT name + ' ' + surname AS Fullname FROM tuserspecialist WHERE del='false' AND name!=''"
```

and then set `DataTextField="Fullname";`